# PickVisualMediaRequest does not show 3rd party app folders

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, androidx

I am trying to use the new [PhotoPicker](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker) to pick an image/video from the gallery:

```
private val selectImageOrVideoFromGalleryResult =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia()) { uri: Uri? ->
        uri?.let {
            viewModel.addMedia(uri)
        }
    }

private fun selectMediaFromGallery() = selectImageOrVideoFromGalleryResult.launch(
      PickVisualMediaRequest(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageAndVideo))
```

The code works as intended, but the issue is that only files from these folders are visible: `Videos`, `Camera`, `Screenshots`, `Downloads`

I do have other folders in my gallery though (eg. `AdobeLightroom`, `DCIM`, `GoPro Exports`, `Instagram`, `WhatsApp Images`). But none of these show up in the picker:

[image]

I assume the main difference is that these folders are created by other apps. How do I make them show up in the picker?

Comment: Please post full paths of those folders.

Comment: The first 2 albums are not a specific folder.  The rest that are visible are in `DCIM/`. The missing folders are from `DCIM/` as well as `Pictures/`

Comment: You have not given full paths of `AdobeLightroom, DCIM, GoPro Exports, Instagram, WhatsApp Images). `

Comment: Those folders are both inside `DCIM/` as well as `Pictures/`. So `DCIM/AdobeLightroom`, `Pictures/Instagram` etc

Comment: Why dont you give full paths of them? How should we know about which DCIM you are talking if you dont give full path.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by full path. is it `Internal Storage/DCIM/GoPro-Exports`? I also don't see how that is relevant to the question. I can give you more info if you can tell me what you're looking for.

Comment: I asked for full [paths. Further i can tell you that pictures taken with Open Camera which are put in /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/OpenCamera are selectable under Photos | Recent. But not under Albums. So yes i believe you when you say that the whole stuff is problematic. Who decided this crappy method?