# Jetpack Photo picker missing folder in album

Tags: android, android-photo-picker

I have many folder which contains jpeg, png etc images but only [3 folder shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaIPV.png) are shown . Is there any way to show all folder which contain images in

```
PickVisualMedia to select a single image or video.
PickMultipleVisualMedia to select multiple images or videos.
```

[Gallery app folder list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LlZg.png)

I find in stack-overflow but no one gave answer. [PickVisualMediaRequest does not show 3rd party app folders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76557577/21697453)